# What's the source of the following props in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The context: I did read about React on w3school, but I didn't find this specific case and I didn't manage to google it as well, that's why I'm asking it here.

I've got the following code:

```
<FooComponent foo="bar">
    {({
      text,
      shouldSort,
    }) => (<div>hello world</div>)
```

I do understand where `props.foo` comes from (I set it manually and it *belongs* to *FooComponent*).

But where *text, shouldSort* props come from (what're their initial values)?

Update: Is it correct that *text, shouldSort* are the props that were set by a parent component?

Comment: You'll have to provide more context...

Comment: `({
      text,
      shouldSort,
    }) => (<div>hello world</div>)` is a function. It acts like `obj => { let text = obj.text; let shouldSort = obj.shouldSort; return <div>hello world</div>; }`.

Comment: @Ry- that's the answer I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<FooComponent foo="bar">
    {({
      text,
      shouldSort,
    }) => (<div>hello world</div>)
```

In this case, `text` and `shouldSort` are props of an anonymous element, which returns `<div>hello world</div>`.

Depending on the context, `text` and `shouldSort` are either set by the parent's parent, or just no component:

Parent's parent:

```
const superParent = () => {
    return <FooComponent foo="bar">...
```

No parent:

```
ReactDOM.render(<FooComponent foo="bar">...
```

The anonymous element is a child of `FooComponent`, which could come from a variety of situations.